# Angular2 line of execution issue

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-services

```
<a class='btn btn-primary' (click)='onSave()' style='width:80px'>
<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right'></i> Save
</a>
```

I have the above call to a typescript method as below

```
onSave(): void  {  

      // this.SaveShipment();
      console.log("before Saving");
      let id = this.shipments.findIndex(i=> i.id === parseInt(this._routeParams.get('id').toString()));
      this.shipments.splice(id,1);
      this._shipmentService.saveShipment((id+1).toString(), this.shipment)
      .subscribe(shipment=> this.shipments.push(shipment));
      this._router.navigate(['ShipmentDetails',{'id':this._routeParams.get('id').toString()}]);
}
```

The last line gets called first before anything happens. Can anyone help on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: And what should happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last line doesn't get called first.

This code probably doesn't work as you expect. This is async code and just schedules code for later execution:

```
  this._shipmentService.saveShipment((id+1).toString(), this.shipment)
  .subscribe(shipment=> this.shipments.push(shipment));
```

This line is executed after above code was scheduled for execution:

```
  this._router.navigate(['ShipmentDetails',{'id':this._routeParams.get('id').toString()}]);
```

This might be what you want:

```
  this._shipmentService.saveShipment((id+1).toString(), this.shipment)
  .subscribe(shipment=> {
    this.shipments.push(shipment);
    this._router.navigate(['ShipmentDetails',{'id':this._routeParams.get('id').toString()}]);
  });
```

This way `this._router.navigate(...)` is executed after the response from `saveShipment()` arrived.